# Reactjs & materialize - stop fixed div when it reaches the footer

Tags: css, reactjs, materialize

I'm working on a project, and would like to have a side panel in a fixed position on the screen (just below the navbar) until it reaches the top of the footer so the two don't overlap.  I've found some suggestions using Jquery, but this project is in react and I am using the materialize css framework.  Here is the code I am working with in `App.js`...

```
<div className="App">
  <Navbar />
  <div className="row" id="landingcontainer">
    <div className="col s3" id="sidebar">
      <Sidebar />
    </div>
  </div>
  <Footer />
</div>
```

And here is what my css looks like:

```
#landingcontainer {
  height: 120vh;
  position: relative;
}

#sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  height: 85vh;
  background-color: plum;
  color: white;
  top: 12vh;
  right: 5px;
}
```

I've also made a sandbox for this: https://codesandbox.io/s/dawn-snow-3cmdv

Right now the when the user scrolls all the way to the bottom, the sidebar overlaps the footer.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using materialize?

Just use this: https://material-ui.com/components/drawers/, 

at least you'll avoid that kind of problems.

If you want to keep using materialize, 

just, tell me why are you using position:fixed ?

Are you aware of that position:fixed make an element 

to stay always in the same place even if the page is scrolled?

Are you sure you didn't want to do this :

```html
#landingcontainer {
  height: 120vh;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom:0;
}

#sidebar {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: plum;
  color: white;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm not sure if the css you provided will work.  I would like the text to stay put as the user continues to scroll.  I'd also like padding around that div

Comment: Sorry but, It make no sense to me, have you done a prototype of what's the final product? (Using Sketch or Lunacy)

Comment: Check out this one: http://jsfiddle.net/0mLzseby/473/ slightly different, but if you scroll all the way down to the footer, it essentially stops being fixed and stacks on top of the footer.  Hope this helps clear things up

Comment: Yeah men, that's a different thing,
you want this : 
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_sticky_element.asp
I think you have to rethink how things should behave in your website,
keep in mind that's the browser support of position:sticky :
https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sticky